WiFi not working after ubuntu update

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Dell XPS 15 9510
I'm also running windows on this laptop

when I enter sudo lshw -C network I get:
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:610-60f memory:616529c000-616529ffff

uname -r gives: 5.14.0-1052-oem
When I entered sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl it said firmware missing. I then updated all firmware in the Firmware updater, that line is not gone, but the network is still unclaimed.

I had this exact problem with the exact same computer.
Step 1 use your USB tether on your phone to get an internet connection. As Bluetooth was also down.
Step 2 do an update, full upgrade, and reboot
Step 3 go into Software and updates.  Find "additional drivers"  And uncheck the Intel Tiger Lake controller at the very bottom of the list where it says other drivers.
Step 4 reboot
Step 5 go back into the terminal and confirm internet connection:  using sudo nmcli device

wow, that worked, thank you so much :)
